# Retrofit with Kotlin traits that include implemented methods

Tags: java, retrofit, traits, kotlin

Traits work well with Retrofit as long as there is no extra method implemented. Depending on return type `RetrofitError: TwitchApi.someMethod: HTTP method annotation is required (e.g., @GET, @POST, etc.).` or `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: TwitchApi.someMethod: Must have either a return type or Callback as last argument.` is thrown.

Is there a way to make retrofit ignore a method that is not annotated with any of `retrofit.http.GET / PUT / ...`  ?

```
public trait SomeApi {

    GET("/endpoint")
    public fun getSomething(Query("user") user: String): Observable<SomeResponse>

    class object {
        public fun create(): SomeApi {
            val restAdapter = RestAdapter.Builder().setEndpoint("http://localhost").build()
            return restAdapter.create<TwitchApi>(javaClass<SomeApi >())
        }
    }

    public fun someMethodThatBreaksRetrofit(user: String) : Int {
        return processResponse(getSomething(user))
    }
}
```

Comment: `trait` has been renamed to `interface`  ... changing that will help other people search and find this question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You shouldn't do like that at all. Fortunately in Kotlin you can use extension functions so

```
interface SomeApi {
    GET("/endpoint")
    fun getSomething(Query("user") user: String): Observable<SomeResponse>
}

fun SomeApi.someMethod(user : String) : Observable<Int>
    = processResponse(getSomething(user))
```

Comment: I believe it look fine in Kotlin so you don't need another hack.

Comment: Thank you :) Kotlin looks better and better :)

Comment: Just note that as far as your getSomething is async (returns Observable) then someMethod actoually should be async too (should return Observable<Int>)

Comment: `trait` has been renamed to `interface`, please update this code sample